# Decoding Failed: Syntax error

Tags: product, import-products

Hi i use csv file to "import"  bulk products. Checking Data with no error.
but when i import the csv file, " Decoding failed: Syntax error"come out if anyone know why ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The 'check data' just checks the columns are okay, it does not parse the whole file.

Here is an approach to find the data that is causing a problem.

Cut your CSV file down to one product and see if that imports. If it does not then cut complex data out of fields until it does import. In that way you can determine if it is a column that is causing the error.

If the one row imports fine then it will be in the rest of your data. Try the same 'bisect' approach. Cut the file in half, try again. If it still not works then cut it in half again.

By taking this approach you will be able to hone in on the data that you are getting wrong.

Without you posting your attributes and your CSV file it is not possible to spot what the mistake is, however, by using the above approach you will be able to find the data that upsets the import.